# How to prevent parameters from VB6 to Oracle using ADO being trimmed

Tags: oracle, plsql, vb6, ado, adodb

I have a VB6 app which calls an Oracle (12) PL/SQL stored procedure. It uses an ADODB connection object.

String parameters passed from the app may have trailing spaces. When Oracle receives them, any trailing spaces are gone.

**I would like the trailing spaces to remain.** I've searched everywhere and can't find any reference online to behaviour of VB, ADO or Oracle which says that trailing spaces are supposed to be trimmed in parameters.

In Oracle, the parameters to the stored procedure are defined as varchar2.
In VB6, I use CreateParameter() to add the params as adVarChar (I've tried other string types and it doesn't help). The call specifies the name, type, direction, size and value.

Just prior to the Execute call, I can check the Command.Parameters collection and verify that any trailing spaces are present.

Oracle references explicitly state that with the varchar2 datatype, trailing spaces are **not** ignored.

Can someone describe if there's an option either in VB or the database which is causing this, and can be turned off?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: IIRC, the trailing spaces ARE stored in the DB, and will be there if you retrieve the value. It's _comparisons_  where they are ignored, ie the SQL language standard says that `Foo   ` is equal to `Foo` when doing WHERE clause and CASE type checks.

Comment: Ah, here's some documentation on the subject. It's from Sql Server rather than Oracle, but it in turn refers to the ansi standard, which Oracle is likely also following (Ansi SQL-92, Section 8.2, <Comparison Predicate>, General rules #3) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626 In Sql Server, you can get around this by doing a LIKE comparison, instead of an equality comparison. No idea if Oracle has the same behavior.

Comment: Hi Joel, I understand what you’re saying RE comparisons, but the actual behaviour I'm finding is that the spaces are simply absent from the parameter as soon as the sproc receives it.  I'm logging the values instantly (in testing), and they are just gone.  In fact, I think the Oracle char type works as you describe, and varchar2 should is designed not to trim the spaces (in a comparison or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you append a null, ie. `chr(0)` to the end of the string that has spaces?

Can you show your code that passes the parameters? What are you passing for length of the string - ie. are you doing a trim before doing len()?

Comment: I tried using the null (in fact it choked with chr(0) – I had to use vbNullChar), but it made no differences.  Spaces are gone once it reaches Oracle.
 
The code is layered in various functions, but an **abridged** version for creating the params is roughly:

Comment: ‘In SetParam
    ' Creates the parameter and appends it to the command object
    ' Assumes it's an input parameter
 
    With mGrid
        .Col = column
        ' CreateParameter chokes if length = 0, or if type is date and the text is "", hence the IIfs
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Name, DataType, adParamInput, IIf(Len(.Text) = 0, 1, Len(.Text)), IIf(.Text = "", Null, .Text))
    End With
 
‘Calling it
Grid.SetParam cmd, eColumns.Domain, "pDomain", adVarChar

Comment: As you can see, there is no trim before passing the length.  I can check the parameter objects just prior to submission and the spaces are present.

Comment: Sorry for poor formatting - I'm doing all this using a phone!

Answer (score 0):

Still not enough points to add a comment though now that I expanded this that it qualifies as a solution.

Oracle Objects for OLE (OO4O) is your best bet for compatibility with modern database versions. Add a reference to oip12.dll and try it out. My quick test case shows that if I send 'abc   ' (that was 3 spaces) as a parameter that the sproc does indeed keep the trailing spaces. I am actually using oip10.dll but the database is 12c. Quick Oracle sample I used.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPTestTrailingSpace
 (F1  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
 ,F2   NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL
 ,DATEIN     DATE NOT NULL
 ) ;

create public synonym TEMPTestTrailingSpace for trace_owner.TEMPTestTrailingSpace;
grant SELECT on TEMPTestTrailingSpace to "TRACE_USER";

Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abc',1,sysdate);
Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abc      ',2,sysdate);
Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abc   ',3,sysdate);
Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abc     ',4,sysdate);
Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abd',5,sysdate);
Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abd   ',6,sysdate);
Insert into TEMPTestTrailingSpace values ('abd    ',7,sysdate);

Create or Replace Procedure getTestRecord
(
  P_PN IN VARCHAR2,
  p_rec OUT number
)
IS
BEGIN
     SELECT f2
     INTO   p_rec
     FROM  TEMPTestTrailingSpace 
     WHERE  f1 = p_pn;
END;
/

create public synonym getTestRecord for trace_owner.getTestRecord;
grant execute on getTestRecord to "TRACE_USER";
```

I use a wrapper around the db access so it's not as easy to share an example. This gets you connected at least.

```
Public ooSession As Object
Public ooDB As Object

Dim ConnStr As String
Set ooSession = New OracleInProcServer.OraSessionClass
ConnStr = userID & "/" & password
Set ooDB = ooSession.OpenDatabase(dataSource, ConnStr, 0&) 'dataSource = Oracle SID or alias in TNSNames.ora file
```

Comment: Thanks for all this detail, and confirming that there is a way of doing this.  I’m in a locked-down environment so unfortunately can’t add OO4O as a reference in the short term.  (In fact it’s so locked down here that I can’t even submit to Stack Exchange – this is all via my phone!)
 
Good to know that there is at least something out there which works as we’d expect.  I’ll look into OO4O and request that it’s made available to Devs here.

Comment: Unfortunately all I've ever used with classic VB is OO4O. It's possible of course there is a solution using whatever ADO provider you're using but I'm not familiar with those. It would be easy to put together a simple test though as I did to prove where things fail (or if you can succeed). If you have access to ODBC provider you could try it as well.